# Which is the maximum size allowed by database in Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to known which is the maximum size allowed by a SharePoint Foundation 2010 database.

Is this version based on SQL Server 2008 Express Edition? Does it have the limit of 4 GB per database or more?

Comment: With a bit of command lines, you can use Windows Internal Database, which is part of Windows. There is no size limitation, but you won't be able to use GUI tools (only command line) and you won't be able to connect from another computer --> this works only for single box with everything on the same box. This fits for very small deployment (in term of number of users/reliability, etc). Not sure if it's a supported scenario.

Comment: Avoid using the WID. This DB is very limited. If you have the option to use the Express edition with 10 GB (in SQL Server 2008 R2) with no fee, why would you want to use the WID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2008 R2 Expression Edition for your storage (R2 is required by SharePoint 2010, or SQL Server 2008 with one of a selection of cumulative updateS: see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx), you have a 10GB storage limit.

You can also install Foundation on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition and up (which has no storage limit per se), but you will of course need to consider license implications if you choose this.

Comment: I think we will start with Express Edition and eventually move to Standard or more if our feedback is positive. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The limiting factor is the SQL Server edition you use, which keeps changing with almost every version of SQL Server.