# Is there a database limit for Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: 2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the maximum size allowed by database in Sharepoint Foundation 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/which-is-the-maximum-size-allowed-by-database-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

Hi

Is there a database limit for Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Thks!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Which is the maximum size allowed by database in Sharepoint Foundation 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/which-is-the-maximum-size-allowed-by-database-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)